# Problems getting the current time in microseconds with a STM32 device

Tags: time, stm32, microcontroller

I am using a stm32f103c8 and I need a function that will return the correct time in microseconds when called from within an interrupt handler. I found the following bit of code online which proports to do that:

```c
uint32_t microsISR()
{
    uint32_t ret;
    uint32_t st = SysTick->VAL;
    uint32_t pending = SCB->ICSR & SCB_ICSR_PENDSTSET_Msk;
    uint32_t ms = UptimeMillis;

    if (pending == 0)
        ms++;

    return ms * 1000 - st / ((SysTick->LOAD + 1) / 1000);
}
```

My understanding of how this works is uses the system clock counter which repeatedly counts down from 8000 (LOAD+1) and when it reaches zero, an interrupt is generated which increments the variable UptimeMills. This gives the time in milliseconds. To get microseconds we get the current value of the system clock counter and divide it by 8000/1000 to give the offset in microseconds. Since the counter is counting down we subtract it from the current time in milliseconds * 1000. (Actually to be correct I believe one should have be added to the # milliseconds in this calculation).

This is all fine and good unless, when this function is called (in an interrupt handler), the system clock counter has already wrapped but the system clock interrupt has not yet been called, then UptimeMillis count will be off by one. This is the purpose of the following lines:

```c
if (pending == 0)
    ms++;
```

Looking at this does not make sense, however. It is incrementing the # ms if there is NO pending interrupt. Indeed if I use this code, I get a large number of glitches in the returned time at the points at which the counter rolls over. So I changed the lines to:

```c
if (pending != 0)
    ms++;
```

This produced much better results but I still get the occasional glitch (about 1 in every 2000 interrupts) which always occurs at a time when the counter is rolling over.

During the interrupt, I log the current value of milliseconds, microseconds and counter value. I find there are two situations where I get an error:

```
  Milli Micros  DT  Counter Pending
1 1661  1660550 826  3602   0
2 1662  1661374 824  5010   0
3 1663  1662196 822  6436   0
4 1663  1662022 -174 7826   0
5 1664  1663847 1825 1228   0
6 1665  1664674 827  2614   0
7 1666  1665501 827  3993   0
```

The interrupts are comming in at a regular rate of about 820us. In this case what seems to be happening between interrupt 3 and 4 is that the counter has wrapped but the pending flag is NOT set. So I need to be adding 1000 to the value and since I fail to do so I get a negative elapsed time.

The second situation is as follows:

```
  Milli Micros  DT  Counter Pending
1 1814  1813535 818  3721   0
2 1815  1814357 822  5151   0
3 1816  1815181 824  6554   0
4 1817  1817000 1819 2      1
5 1817  1816817 -183 1466   0
6 1818  1817637 820  2906   0
```

This is a very similar situation except in this case the counter has NOT yet wrapped and yet I am already getting the pending interrupt flag which causes me to erronously add 1000.

Clearly there is some kind of race condition between the two competing interrupts. I have tried setting the clock interrupt priority both above and below that of the external interrupt but the problem persists.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to deal with this problem or a suggestion for a different approach to get the time is microseconds within an interrupt handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `UptimeMillis` *before and after* `SysTick->VAL` to ensure a rollover has not occurred.

```c
uint32_t microsISR()
{
    uint32_t ms = UptimeMillis;
    uint32_t st = SysTick->VAL;

    // Did UptimeMillis rollover while reading SysTick->VAL?
    if (ms != UptimeMillis)
    {
        // Rollover occurred so read both again.
        // Must read both because we don't know whether the
        // rollover occurred before or after reading SysTick->VAL.
        // No need to check for another rollover because there is
        // no chance of another rollover occurring so quickly.
        ms = UptimeMillis;
        st = SysTick->VAL;
    }

    return ms * 1000 - st / ((SysTick->LOAD + 1) / 1000);
}
```

Or here is the same idea in a do-while loop.

```c
uint32_t microsISR()
{
    uint32_t ms;
    uint32_t st;

    // Read UptimeMillis and SysTick->VAL until
    // UptimeMillis doesn't rollover.
    do
    {
        ms = UptimeMillis;
        st = SysTick->VAL;
    } while (ms != UptimeMillis);

    return ms * 1000 - st / ((SysTick->LOAD + 1) / 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was able to get your solution to work but a note for anyone that stumbles across this question, it does NOT work 'out of the box'. In fact I had already tried this approach without success. The problem is that by default the priority for the system clock interrupt is 15 (which is the lowest priority). Hence my interrupt (which is at priority 3) cannot be interrupted by the system clock and therefor UptimeMillis could not possibly change while in my interrupt handler.

Comment: This is why, I presume, the code was added to check the interrupt pending register in the ISR version of this function. However if you change the priorities of the interrupts so that the clock interrupt is higher (i.e. lower number) than the external interrupt, then my interrupt handler can be interrupted and the code appears to work. I am not 100% sure that it has eliminated all possibilities for a glitch if the timing was just perfect, but I have run multiple long tests and no glitches were detected.

Thanks again for your help.